# Error in loadnamespace when knitting R_markdown to PDF

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

This is the first time I use R_Markdown

I created a new R_Markdown and am trying to knit it to PDF. When I do it I get the following error

```
processing file: R_markdown.Rmd
  |..........                                                            |  14%
  ordinary text without R code

  |....................                                                  |  29%
label: setup (with options) 
List of 1
 $ include: logi FALSE

  |..............................                                        |  43%
  ordinary text without R code

  |........................................                              |  57%
label: cars
  |..................................................                    |  71%
  ordinary text without R code

  |............................................................          |  86%
label: pressure (with options) 
List of 1
 $ echo: logi FALSE

  |......................................................................| 100%
  ordinary text without R code


output file: R_markdown.knit.md

"C:/Program Files/RStudio/bin/pandoc/pandoc" +RTS -K512m -RTS R_markdown.utf8.md --to latex --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+tex_math_single_backslash --output R_markdown.tex --lua-filter "C:\Users\faiel\Documents\R\win-library\4.0\rmarkdown\rmarkdown\lua\pagebreak.lua" --lua-filter "C:\Users\faiel\Documents\R\win-library\4.0\rmarkdown\rmarkdown\lua\latex-div.lua" --self-contained --highlight-style tango --pdf-engine pdflatex --variable graphics --variable "geometry:margin=1in" 
Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
  namespace 'xfun' 0.17 is already loaded, but >= 0.19 is required
Calls: <Anonymous> ... namespaceImportFrom -> asNamespace -> loadNamespace
Execution halted
```

I can't understand why this is happening. I tried the following

```
install.packages("rmarkdown")
```

and

```
update.packages(ask = FALSE, checkBuilt = TRUE)
tinytex::tlmgr_update()
```

But without any luck

Answer (score 7):

**Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) :
namespace ***'xfun'*** 0.17 is already loaded, but >= 0.19 is required**

If you found an error as above you can use the below solution to remove the error.
And the same method can be used for any package.(in place of xfun any package name could be present).

**Solution:**
In RStudio, Navigate to ->Tools->Check For package updates, here you can select the packages and update.
If this doesn't work update the R version and try updating packages.

By performing the above method the package will be updated to a newer version.

Comment: Ranjan, Welcome to SO! It's nice that you've included a way to use RStudio's GUI to update packages. I think your answer could use a little more depth (e.g. note how @user2554330's answer pinpointed the offending package) so that others who find their way to this answer can clearly see what problem your proposed solution solves and how.

Answer (score 1):

Answer from Ranjan Shetty works. https://stackoverflow.com/users/15898034/ranjan-shetty

Just reinstaled xfun package, and issue solved.

(I don't comment because I haven't enough points)

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, vote up the answers that you find helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34088143)

Answer (score 0):

The version of `xfun` that's on CRAN is currently 0.18.  Apparently you're using some other package that requires `xfun` version 0.19.  So you need to stop using that non-CRAN package, or update `xfun` from Github or some other untested source.

You can run `remotes::update_packages()` to search lots of places for updates.  I don't recommend relying on non-CRAN packages:  they may change tomorrow in an incompatible way.

To find out which non-CRAN packages were installed by the `remotes` package (or `devtools`), you can run

```
subset(as.data.frame(installed.packages(fields="RemoteType")), !is.na(RemoteType))
```

However, I don't think that will detect packages that were installed by downloading the `.tar.gz` or `.zip` file.  I don't know how to detect those.

Comment: Thank you. I don't think I have ever installed a non-CRAN package, what would be the best way to check this and use the CRAN's  **xfun** ?

Comment: @FrAiello:  I've edited my answer to give a partial response.

Comment: I encountered a similar problem when using R markdown. I got the solution by simply updating the packages in Rstudio.

Answer (score 0):

I have had to same Problem under RStudio 1.4.1103.0 and R 4.0.4 (Win10, 20H2). The problem appeared after I updated the installed packages. I can't say which ones exactly, because I updated all packages.

```
Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : namespace 'xfun' 0.17 is already loaded, but >= 0.19 is required
```

Xfun could not be updated.
I uninstalled rstudio and then installed the latest version of RStudio (11.04.) and R (4.0.5.) respectively. After that I could update xfun (0.22) again and the problem was **solved**.

All in all quite time consuming and I didn't quite understand the problem. Maybe there are better ways?